# display rows of same data in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the sql query

```
SET @cumulative_sum := 0;
SELECT fct_sales.datDate, @cumulative_sum := @cumulative_sum + fct_sales.dblTotal AS     
cumulative_sum
FROM fct_sales
where
fct_sales.intProductID=40
and
fct_sales.datDate
between
'2011-01-01'
and
'2011-01-10'
 ORDER BY fct_sales.datDate ASC
```

which does fine and giving me the result table as

```
 _______________________________
 |     datDate|  Cumulative_sum|
 |____________|________________|          
 | 2011-01-02 |   5005         |
 |____________|________________|
 |2011-01-04  |   7007         |
 |____________|________________|
```

However, what I require is this:

```
  _____________________________
 |     datDate|  Cumulative_sum|
 |____________|________________| 
 |  2011-01-01|  5005          |
 |____________|________________| 
 |  2011-01-02|  5005          |
 |____________|________________| 
 |  2011-01-03|  5005          |
 |____________|________________| 
 |  2011-01-04|  7007          |
 |____________|________________| 
 |  2011-01-05|  7007          |
 |____________|________________| 
 |  2011-01-06|  7007          |
 |____________|________________| 
 |  2011-01-07|  7007          |
 |____________|________________| 
 |  2011-01-08|  7007          |
 |____________|________________| 
 |  2011-01-09|  7007          |
 |____________|________________| 
 |  2011-01-10|  7007          |
 |____________|________________|
```

How do I accomplish this??

Comment: please provide some content of fct_sales table

Comment: Columns of fct_sales:  

intProductID (foreign key)

intCustomerID (foreign key)

intStoreID (foreign key)

intQuantity

dblCost

dblUnitPrice

dblTotal

datDate (foreign key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi basically for this query you need 3 things:

1. Set of Dates
2. Join fct_sales with same table to get nextDate
3. Make set of Dates and joined fct_sales.

If you want that 5005 sum would be in date 2011-01-01 I think it's impossible, because if there more than 2 Cumulative_sums in list they gona overlap each other...

Example not pretty, because you need Range of Dates. Sometimes in db are Time table which gonna help to reduce query code. If this not help you, then at least a little bit will be useful:)

**[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dceac/25)**

So here my example:

```
 SELECT
    a.Date
    ,b.Cumulative_sum
    FROM
      (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY, '%Y-%m-%d') AS Date
       FROM
         (SELECT 0 AS a
          UNION ALL SELECT 1
          UNION ALL SELECT 2
          UNION ALL SELECT 3
          UNION ALL SELECT 4
          UNION ALL SELECT 5
          UNION ALL SELECT 6
          UNION ALL SELECT 7
          UNION ALL SELECT 8
          UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS a CROSS
       JOIN
         (SELECT 0 AS a
          UNION ALL SELECT 1
          UNION ALL SELECT 2
          UNION ALL SELECT 3
          UNION ALL SELECT 4
          UNION ALL SELECT 5
          UNION ALL SELECT 6
          UNION ALL SELECT 7
          UNION ALL SELECT 8
          UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS b CROSS
       JOIN
         (SELECT 0 AS a
          UNION ALL SELECT 1
          UNION ALL SELECT 2
          UNION ALL SELECT 3
          UNION ALL SELECT 4
          UNION ALL SELECT 5
          UNION ALL SELECT 6
          UNION ALL SELECT 7
          UNION ALL SELECT 8
          UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS c) a,
       (SELECT 
        fc1.datDate, 
        fc1.Cumulative_sum, 
         (SELECT MIN(fc2.datDate)  
          from fc fc2 
          WHERE fc1.datDate < fc2.datDate ) AS nextDate
    from fc fc1) b
      where (a.Date between '2011-01-01' and '2011-01-10')
        AND a.Date>=b.datDate 
        AND a.Date < COALESCE(b.nextDate, '2011-01-11')
      ORDER BY a.Date, b.Cumulative_sum
```

Result:

```
DATE    CUMULATIVE_SUM
2011-01-02  5005
2011-01-03  5005
2011-01-04  7007
2011-01-05  7007
2011-01-06  7007
2011-01-07  7007
2011-01-08  7007
2011-01-09  7007
2011-01-10  7007
```

Query example with your query data:

```
SET @cumulative_sum := 0;
SELECT
    a.Date
    ,b.Cumulative_sum
    FROM
      (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY, '%Y-%m-%d') AS Date
       FROM
         (SELECT 0 AS a
          UNION ALL SELECT 1
          UNION ALL SELECT 2
          UNION ALL SELECT 3
          UNION ALL SELECT 4
          UNION ALL SELECT 5
          UNION ALL SELECT 6
          UNION ALL SELECT 7
          UNION ALL SELECT 8
          UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS a CROSS
       JOIN
         (SELECT 0 AS a
          UNION ALL SELECT 1
          UNION ALL SELECT 2
          UNION ALL SELECT 3
          UNION ALL SELECT 4
          UNION ALL SELECT 5
          UNION ALL SELECT 6
          UNION ALL SELECT 7
          UNION ALL SELECT 8
          UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS b CROSS
       JOIN
         (SELECT 0 AS a
          UNION ALL SELECT 1
          UNION ALL SELECT 2
          UNION ALL SELECT 3
          UNION ALL SELECT 4
          UNION ALL SELECT 5
          UNION ALL SELECT 6
          UNION ALL SELECT 7
          UNION ALL SELECT 8
          UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS c) a,
       (SELECT
    fc1.datDate,
    fc1.Cumulative_sum,
         (SELECT MIN(fc2.datDate) AS datDate
            FROM (SELECT fct_sales.datDate, @cumulative_sum := @cumulative_sum + fct_sales.dblTotal AS     
                    cumulative_sum
                  FROM fct_sales
                 where
                fct_sales.intProductID=40
                and fct_sales.datDate between '2011-01-01' and '2011-01-10') fc2
          WHERE fc1.datDate < fc2.datDate ) AS nextDate
        FROM (SELECT fct_sales.datDate, @cumulative_sum := @cumulative_sum + fct_sales.dblTotal AS     
              cumulative_sum
             FROM fct_sales
             where
             fct_sales.intProductID=40
            and fct_sales.datDate between '2011-01-01' and '2011-01-10' ) fc1) b
      where (a.Date between '2011-01-01' and '2011-01-10')
        AND a.Date>=b.datDate 
        AND a.Date < COALESCE(b.nextDate, '2011-01-11')
      ORDER BY a.Date, b.Cumulative_sum
```

Comment: Thank you Justin.. that was really helpful.
As I am new to this, I wonder, why we need such a long query and these much functions to retrieve data from a single table. Anyways, 
thank you.. so much for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

As your data is not appropriate to solve your problem..
But whatever you provided I think this will help you..

```
SELECT datDate, Cumulative_sum from fct_sales where Cumulative_sum > 5005 AND Cumulative_sum < 7007 AND intProductID = '40' ORDER BY datDate ASC
```

Comment: Thank you user1573254.

           That one didn't worked. In fact, it gave me a blank result set.Please let me know what all information you will be needing ??
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT datDate, Cumulative_sum FROM fct_sales WHERE intProductID='40' AND datDate BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-01-10' GROUP BY datDate
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
    That didn't worked. Just changed the order.

       Will you be needing any more information on my table?? 
Please let me know. Thank you.